# In Woocommerce API, which hook for a specific order status for a webhook?

Tags: woocommerce, webhooks, hook-woocommerce, orders

I need to subscribe to a webhook that will fire when an order is complete (having been completely paid for).  Which webhook will do this?

I've seen there is a `woocommerce_payment_complete` action, but I imagine this will fire for each payment that is made in the event of there being multiple payments on a single order?  e.g. a customer may make a part-payment on credit card 1 and a part payment on credit card 2.  Surely each of these will cause the `woocommerce_payment_complete` event to fire?  Or am I missing something in the documentation?

I'm hoping for a webhook like `order.complete`, which fires when the order is now in the warehouse.  Payment is received, and fulfillment can begin.  But I'm not seeing such a webhook in the documentation.

---

**Edit:**

So I found [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-orders/) link which explains the Woocommerce order lifecycle, which tells me that `Processing` is the status/event that I am interested in.

However, I'm not seeing this event in the [official Webhook reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)

What webhook will fire when an order enters this `processing` status?

---

**Edit 2:** *(after @LoicTheAztec's answer)*
When I try to create the webhook using the WooCommerce API (`https://mysite/wp-json/wc/v3/webhooks`), with the following payload:

```
{
  "name": "Order Processed",
  "topic": "woocommerce_order_status_processing",
  "delivery_url": "https://mycallbackapp.herokuapp.com/yo8i78yo"
}
```

I get back the following `400 Bad Request` response:

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_shop_webhook_invalid_topic",
    "message": "Webhook topic is required and must be valid.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 3:**

Finally **the topic** needs to be `topic.woocommerce_order_status_processing`

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, however please advise how I should create this webhook (I have edited my question to show the error I get)

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I figured it out!  The topic needs to be `topic.woocommerce_order_status_processing`.  If you add your comment as an answer, I will mark it as such!

Comment: I have added my comment as answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't find it because there are some WooCommerce **composite hooks** and the right one to be used in your case is: [`woocommerce_order_status_$STATUS_TRANSITION[to\]`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#360) where `$STATUS_TRANSITION` is your desired *(transition)* order status.

So for **"processing"** order status the hook will be: **`woocommerce_order_status_processing`**
*or for "completed" order status your hook will be `woocommerce_order_status_completed`*.